# Touch event up and down in andengine

Tags: android, button, andengine, effects

I added a srpite image.I will use it as button.When I press it,it should effect like in code below.It works only when I wrote toouch.event.action_down.But I want when my finger is up, the button should return stuation beforel like in code below.but it doesn't work.

```
           Sprite spriteMusicPicture1 = new Sprite(726.0f, 350.0f, mFaceTextureRegion7){
                @Override
                public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pAreaTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                    switch(pAreaTouchEvent.getAction()) {
                        case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                    
                            this.setScale(1.25f);
                            this.setAlpha(0.5f);



                        case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:  
                            this.setScale(1.0f);
                            this.setAlpha(1.0f);




                            }
                            return true;
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After each `case` you have to put a **break;**  otherwise it will not stop and continue executing all the lines